# I'm getting a jQuery error (n.easing...) in inspector and I don't know how to deal with it

Tags: jquery

The line that I'm getting in inspector goes like this:

> Uncaught TypeError: n.easing[this.easing] is not a function

After inspecting the code, I have no idea what to do about it, nor where it came from. I don't know what jQuery is, nor would I know how to edit it.

Any suggestions on how to proceed? Is there some additional information that I should provide here?

Website is www.rfm-inc.com. This happens on the site when I change the screen size to less than 768px.

---

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25kvZ.png) is what I'm seeing in inspector. As I've indicated in comments below, I don't know how to narrow the code down (see the red highlighted line in the window). There are thousands of characters more than I can include in this post.

Maybe a better way to ask this question is "How do I use inspector (or another tool) to track down the problem?".

When I click on the gray link that reads "jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4", I navigate to another window that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csion.jpg).

Comment: What code are you trying to run? Where has the reference to jQuery come from?

Comment: the first thing to troubleshoot when you received "not a function" in the console is make sure you have include jquery in your project and all dependent scripts.

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Comment: This is a javscript error. JQuery is a javascript framework. Either this is happening in an external javascript file (would be in the `<head>` as a `<script>` with a URL), or within a `<script>` as cod.

Comment: Okay. I'm a beginner and I have no idea how to proceed. The lines of code that I can get in inspector are thousands of characters too long to post here, and I think I'll likely be here for days trying to figure out which "minimal" piece of code to include. I don't know how to "make sure you have include jquery in your project and all dependent scripts".

Comment: @gwar9 - Do you have any more tips on how to do that? I am a beginner, and I'd like to learn, but I don't know where to start with that.

Comment: @MCMXCII - Where do I go/what do I do to find answers to your questions? I'm just learning and could really use some more direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @j08691 - I'm willing to work more on coming up with a "Minimal, Complete, Verifiable" example. I just don't know how. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: @Santi - Any more advice on how I would go about determining the root cause and fixing it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @nmeffert If you are interested in learning jQuery there are hundreds of tutorials out there on the internet, I would personally recommend https://www.codecademy.com/.

Comment: @MCMXCII - Thanks for the advice. I like Code Academy too, but I find that forums like this are most helpful for me, since we can be very application-focused here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, I ended up rebuilding the site in Bootstrap. The other site was built on a Wordpress theme that seemed to be throwing up these errors. But I never figured out how to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

To include jquery and your depended js files your document should look something like this:

Include your jquery before you add any other script.

+Note that is an example you did not include any code or any of the names of the libraries you are trying to use.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"> <!--example of a meta tag-->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> <!--example of includes css file-->
  
<!---Add jquery here--->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  
<!---example of a dependent js library gets loaded after jquery--->
<script src="js/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>  

</head>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @gwar9. I tried to add my code, but it's a LOT, and I wasn't allowed to post that many characters. Hmmm. Any other ideas on how to narrow it down, or workaround? Again, thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: @nmeffert The console is telling you the problem this.easing is not a function which likely means you are missing a script that defines that function. Make sure you have included all your libraries under your jquery script.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @gwar9. I have no idea how to do that. I am using a theme and all I've been doing is making CSS changes. I made a few minor chances to .php files, but almost everything is CSS (which is the only language I—sort of—know).

Comment: @nmeffert can you post the link to your website ?

Comment: I'm not allowed to, based on # of links in post. Maybe here: http://www.rfm-inc.com